# How do I install the runtime version of vim?

Tags: installation, vim

How do I go about installing the runtime version of Vim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ubuntu ships `vim-tiny` by default. To get the real deal (which includes `vim-runtime`), simply run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

I would normally include a Software Center link, but you seem like a pretty technical fellow. [image: ;)]